# Every monad in Set induces an operad

Tags: category-theory, operads

$\require{AMScd}$I am fighting with an exercise in Leinster's *Higher operads*: in short, [Example 2.2.11](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0305049) says that every monad on $\bf Set$ gives an operad taking the sequence of $T(n)$, where $n$ is an $n$-elements set. He then says

> Informally, composition is substitution of words; formally, the composition functions can be written down in terms of the monad structure on T (exercise)

Doing this exercise seems very difficult. What am I missing?

**Attempt at a solution**

I am convinced that the unit $\eta_1 : 1 \to T1$ is the unit map of the operad, and that multiplication is defined as follows: given positive integers $m, n_1,\dots, n_m$, if $n=\sum n_i$ I define
$$
\begin{CD}
Tm\times Tn_1\times\dots Tn_m \\
@VVTm\times\iota_1\times \iota_m V\\
Tm\times Tn\times\dots\times Tn \\
@VVTm\times a V\\
Tm\times TTn^{Tm} \\
@VV\epsilon V\\
TTn \\
@VV\mu_nV\\
Tn
\end{CD}
$$
where

- $i_k : Tn_k\to Tn$ is the image under $T$ of the embedding $n_k\to n = n_1\sqcup\dots\sqcup n_m$.
- I blur the distinction between the product $\prod_{i=1}^m Tn_i$ and the set of functions $m\to Tn$.
- $a$ is the action of $T$ on morphisms.

This is a wannabe multiplication map $\gamma_{m,\vec n} : Tm \times Tn_1\times Tn_m \to Tn$.

Now, I have to verify suitable axioms. Unitality is not a problem: it follows from the monad axioms. Intuitively, associativity shall entail associativity for $\gamma$, but the diagram I have to check is, well... huge.

Let us consider positiv integers $m, p_1,\dots, p_m$ and $q_{ij}$ where $i=1,\dots,m$ and $j=1,\dots, p_i$. Associativity amounts to the commutativity of the following huge square:

[image]

($\blacksquare$ is a trick to save some space: in the upper horizontal row, the $q_{ij}$ are untouched)

Moreover, I adopted the following shorthands: $Q_i := \sum_j q_{ij}$, $P=\sum_i p_i$, $Q=\sum_i Q_i$; $T\vec p := Tp_1\times\dots\times Tp_m$ and $T\vec q_i := Tq_{i1}\times\dots\times Tq_{i p_i}$.

I can fill all the squares I have drawn with something making them commutative; I see no way to go on and finish. At some point things become *really* dirty, as I have to use the trick above (treat a number as a finite set, and sum as coproduct) over the diagram of inclusions
$$
\begin{CD}
{} @. {} @. q_{ij}\\
@. @. @VVV\\
{} @. p_i @>>> Q_i \\
@.  @VVV @VVV \\
m @>>> P @>>> Q
\end{CD}
$$
It seems quite clear that this approach is not the smartest one, but I am quite stubborn and now I want to finish the proof this way. Advices? Corrections?